# quick sort in python using recursion

Tags: python, sorting, quicksort

I'm trying to do quicksort in python using following code

```
def quicksort(a, left, right):
    if left < right:
        i = left;
        j = right + 1;
        pivot = a[left];

        while True:
            while True:
                i=i+1
                if a[i] > pivot or i >= right:
                    break

            while True:
                j=j-1
                if a[j] < pivot:
                    break

            if i < j:
                a[i], a[j] = a[j],a[i];
            if i>j:
                break

        a[left], a[j] = a[j],a[left]

        quicksort(a, left, j - 1);
        quicksort(a, j + 1, right);
```

I'm getting error

```
[4, 5, 8, 2, 1, 10, 99, 3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/suraj/workspace/DSPS/quicksort/quicksort_py.py", line 36, in <module>
quicksort(a, 0, 7);
File "/home/suraj/workspace/DSPS/quicksort/quicksort_py.py", line 28, in quicksort
quicksort(a, j + 1, right);
File "/home/suraj/workspace/DSPS/quicksort/quicksort_py.py", line 28, in quicksort
quicksort(a, j + 1, right);
File "/home/suraj/workspace/DSPS/quicksort/quicksort_py.py", line 12, in quicksort
if a[i] > pivot or i >= right:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I know other ways to implement quicksort but I want correction in this code.
The same logic works with c++
please help me I'm new with python

Comment: What did you expect? You never check that `i` is actually a valid index into `a`.

Comment: Order of evaluation is very important. Change your code to this: `if i >= right or a[i] > pivot:`

Comment: If you enter `quicksort` with `i` equal to the length of `a` minus one, then the first thing that will happen is `i=i+1`. Then `i` is out of range of your list, and you get an error.